# Wordpress pull Blog Post

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm designing a theme for wordpress. I need advice on how I would construct it.

At the bottom of my Frontpage/Home I will put a snippets (a title and a short description of blog post) of what is new in my Blog .

Preview:
[image]

Question:

What approach should I use? I can make the bottom page widget ready and will just use widget or will use PHP to pull details in my 'blog' page (I dunno how to do it php, a link would be useful)

what is the proper approach? I'm designing it for a client. My concern is If I would make it widget ready, client would have to install the widget. If I would do it on PHP, (I have no resource and idea in doing that )

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to know some PHP and JavaScript if you want to make a WP theme from scratch. Otherwise I would suggest to modify an existing one.

[Here is the theme development help from WP.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to run a loop, in which you'll retrieve the posts from the database (Wordpress handles that) and show them as needed.

[The Loop In Action](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop_in_Action) and 
[Building Custom Wordpress Themes](http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/building-custom-wordpress-theme/)

Hope that helps